# Android super.onTouch

Tags: android

I am adding a touch listener to a view.

*here is the **code***:

```
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return super.onTouch(v, event);
        }
    });
```

But I keep getting the **error**:

*The method onTouch(View, MotionEvent) is undefined for the type Object*.

Why do I keep getting this error. Is there something I need to add to my app to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must not call super in the `onTouch`-Method: Instead return false or true like you need it. 
(JavaDoc: True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.)

```
 view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the logs? Maybe there is an error elsewhere in the code.

Comment: one second, I just need to try one thing

Comment: @superuser make sure you're not calling the ontouch of the view within the ontouch handler, that will cause a stackoverflow as they'll keep calling each other

Comment: @Thommy I was wondering if there is a way to make the function only return true once.

Comment: Create a boolean that is true before and false after the first call. 
`boolean once = true;
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

if (once){ once = false;
            return true;}
else return false;
        }
    });`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting it because you're actually implementing an interface called View.OnTouchListener rather than extending the View

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. How can I fix my code to make it work?

Comment: I believe v.onTouchEvent(event); would do the trick but I'd imagine that would be getting called anyway

Comment: so how would I do v.onTouch(v, event)?

Comment: View doesn't contain a public onTouch method, so you can't do that. Why do you want to call the View's on touch within the on touch handler?

Comment: I just thought that super.onTouch would only return true once

Comment: Ah okay, go with Thommy's answer